# How can I change the pose of a 3D model I download?

Tags: pose-mode

For example if I were to download the following file: https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/various/serpent-kodoku

How can I straighten the model out or put it in a different pose which I will then later 3D print?

Comment: hello, if this model is free, please share so that we can take a look: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: That was just an example model. I am asking in general with any 3D models what would be the best and easiest way to change the pose of an existing 3D model that is already in a pose.

Comment: each case is different, so there is not one unique solution for all the cases, it may be with armature, of with the Pose brush in Sculpt mode, etc... as for your snake it seems rather complicated to make a cylinder from a spiral, maybe someone has the answer